# Is this EER diagram correct for my application?

Tags: database, database-design, class-diagram

I have to develop a sample analysis web app. I usually program the app with given EER diagram, but this time I've to do it myself.

[image]

I explain:

There will be more than 1 type of analysis (*tipos_analisis* table) and a lot of parameters (*parametros* table). Also, *tipos_analisis* table has a number of rows (*num_filas* column). This will be for how many analysis of same type will have to be created. Then, the user will have to pair different types of analysis with their corresponding parameters. Will be store in N:M table *parametros_tipos_analisis*.

Then, I have samples (*muestras* table). From samples, user will create an analysis of 1 or more samples. When analysis is created, N rows are created to be filled. This rows are created based on each analysis type, his number of rows and their parameters. e.g. if they are two analysis types with 10 parameters each, and one of them have 2 number of rows while the other one has 1, this analysis will create 30 analysis rows with *result* column each one to be filled later on in analysis_rows table (*lineas_analisis* table):

- Analysis_type1_1 x10 parameters.
- Analysis_type1_2 x10 parameters.
- Analysis_type2_1 x10 parameters

So, my question is, this will be appropiate EER diagram for my app explanation? Or should I change something? Database model is not my best and want to be sure about it before start to programming and to avoid future errors...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Makes sense in general. The only error I found is that `muestras` to `analisis` is probably an `M:N` relation. One sample can be used in many analysis instances, one analysis can use many samples.

A few extra thoughts:

1. `lineas_analisis` will probably have more columns (result time, created/updated, etc.)
2. `parametros.parent_id` has no self-reference. I expected a foreign key to the same table.
3. Please, only use one language for naming. `created_by`, `created_at`, `parent_id`, `order` are all English, whereas the rest is Spanish. I tend to always use English, but any ONE language will do. :)

Good luck developing!

Comment: Ty for your answer! For parts:
`muestras` to `analsis` is 1:N. One analysis can have 1 or more samples but one sample can only have one analysis (keep in mind that analysis will have 1 or more type on analysis creating multiple `lineas_analisis`, where results will be inserted)
1. Yea, it will. Like created_at, updated_at, created_by, updated_by... etc but are relevant here.
2. `parent_id` is an `id` from same table, to do groups and subgroups (again relevant for app functionality, so no problem!)
3. Yea, the problem is that timestamp and stuff does laravel its own, but no problem at all.

Comment: My doubt is about relation with `lineas_analisis`. Should have relation with `tipos_analisis` and `parametros` or directly with N:M table `parametros_tipos_analisis`?

Comment: `parametros_tipos_analisis` is not an entity, so you can't bind to it. Current solution sounds right to me.